# Check of file contains a line beginning with 'xxx' but not 'yxxx'

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am writing a small bash script that checks whether to execute `makeindex` or not if a .tex file contains the line `\makeindex`. The MakeIndex run would not be run if the command is commented-out.

How do I check that a file, say `source.tex` has the line?

I know that I need grep—I am, however, fairly new to regexes and bash scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your title and question are asking different things. As a couple people have already answered your title, I'll address your question.

As I recall, tex comments are `%`. So we'll search for a line that contains `\makeindex` without a `%` before it on the line:

```
grep '^[^%]*\\makeindex' source.tex
#grep -- the program we're running, obviously.
#    '                 ' -- Single quotes to keep bash from interpreting special chars.
#     ^ -- match the beginning of a line
#      [  ] -- match characters in the braces.
#       ^  -- make that characters not in the braces.
#        % -- percent symbol, the character (in the braces) we do not want to match.
#          * -- match zero or more of the previous item (non-percent-symbols)
#           \\ -- a backslash; a single one is used to escape strings like '\n'.
#             makeindex -- the literal string "makeindex"
#                        source.tex-- Input file
```

Sample:

```
$ grep '\\end' file.tex
51:src/file.h\end{DoxyCompactItemize}
52:%src/file.h\end{DoxyCompactItemize}
53:src/%file.h\end{DoxyCompactItemize}
54:    %\end{DoxyCompactItemize}
55:src/file.h\end{DoxyCompactItemize}%
$ grep '^[^%]*\\end' file.tex
51:src/file.h\end{DoxyCompactItemize}
55:src/file.h\end{DoxyCompactItemize}%
$
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to anchor match to the beginning of line it's

```
grep ^xxx files...
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to use this in a `[[ $myvar =~ ^\s*xxx ]]` fashion without having to iterate through the whole line?

Comment: I'd do something like `[[ "$myvar" = "${myvar#prefix}" ]]` -- if variable with the said prefix cut off is the same then it has no such prefix.

Comment: BTW, why do you need to iterate through the whole line and what do you mean by "the whole line"?

Comment: You mean, you have the whole file in variable? I think it's more efficient to use grep.

Comment: Now I figured what you were asking about, thanks to Kevin's answer. I'll upvote him.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one call to `awk`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if awk '/^xxx/{f=1}/^yyy/{f=0}END{if(!f)exit 1}' file; then
  echo "file OK"
else
  echo "file BAD"
fi
```